¿Cómo puedo utilizar función en JavaScript?
como puedo utilizar función para no repetir un código de una variable y obtener impreso en la consola el numero mayor.
let num1 = 1;
let num2 = 2;
let num3 = 3;

let mayor;

if (num1 > num2){
    mayor = num1
}else{
    mayor = num2
}
if (num3 > mayor){
console.log ("el mayor es" , num3)
}else{
    console.log("el mayor es" , mayor) 
}


Puedes ser más clara?

Hay dos maneras de hacer esto.
La primera (con una función que escribas) es:
function MayorDeDos(num1, num2) {
  if (num1 > num2) return num1;
  return num2;
}

let num1 = 1;
let num2 = 2;
let num3 = 3;
let mayor;

mayor = MayorDeDos(num1, num2);
mayor = MayorDeDos(mayor, num3);
console.log("el mayor es", mayor);

El segundo (con la función Math.max() de Javascript) es:
let num1 = 1;
let num2 = 2;
let num3 = 3;
let mayor;

mayor = Math.max(num1, num2, num3);
console.log("el mayor es", mayor);

o simplemente:
console.log("el mayor es:", Math.max(1,2,3));

